# How to convert this Regular Expression to 'named group re' Python

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I need to convert the following Regular Expression in *named groups re* format. Which I don't fully understand yet.

```
 info = re.findall(
                r'.*\/dev\/(sd.):[.\s]*0[xX][1-9a-fA-F]+[.\s]*0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+[.\s]*(\S+).*', content
            )
```

An string to test if it works could be (matching with `sda`, `13D0A016FTR7`) :

```
/dev/sda:   0x1 0x0  '13D0A016FTR7'
```

At the end it should be able to use the `info` variable in the following way:

```
info[0][0] = sda
info[0][1] = 13D0A016FTR7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my question:

```
content = "/dev/sda:   0x1 0x0  '13D0A016FTR7'"

info = re.search(r'.*\/dev\/(?P<disk>sd.):[.\s]*0[xX][1-9a-fA-F]+[.\s]*0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+[.\s]*(?P<serial>\S+).*', content)

info.group('disk')
'sda'

info.group('serial')
"'13D0A016FTR7'"
```